# Json file is being showed in data bricks

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read the JSON file in pyspark. When tried to read as df it is reading but when asked to display its shows up an error:-

```
df = spark.read.format("json") \
     .load(path)
df.show()
```

error:

```
AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
```

my JSON data looks as follows:-

```
[
  {
    "Rollno": 19,
    "sex": "female",
    "Rank": 9,
    "Date": "11/12/2020"
  },
  {
    "Rollno": 18,
    "sex": "male",
    "bmi": 7,
    "Date": "11/12/2020"
  },

and so on.
```

Why am I getting this error? Am I reading it incorrectly? What is the best way to read and display a JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark by default is expecting that each line contains the full JSON string.  If your file consists of the just single JSON object then you may need to use `multiLine` option of the [JSON reader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json), like this:

```py
df = spark.read.option("multiLine", 'true').json(path)
```

Comment: Tried this but the same error. AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the